# Did session state variables disappear in MVC Net Core? What is replacement syntax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Did session state variables disappear in MVC Net Core? I receive error "The Name Session does not exist in current context." What is the replacement syntax?

```
Session["testitem"] = "test"
```

Would this be the new replacement?

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("testitem", "test");
```

Comment: Yes, that's the way the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.0) also suggests.
I recommend taking a look at all sections of that document, as there are some common pitfalls you probably want to avoid.

Comment: if you want points, feel free to write comment and maybe example in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session state variable syntax changed,

InDieTasten :

"Yes, that's the way the documentation also suggests. I recommend taking a look at all sections of that document, as there are some common pitfalls you probably want to avoid."